# Svg distorted when width is increased

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I am no good in SVG and facing one issue with one below

```
<div class="position-absolute w-100">
                    <svg class="waves waves-sm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 40" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
                      <defs>
                        <path id="card-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"></path>
                      </defs>
                      <g class="moving-waves">
                        <use xlink:href="#card-wave" x="48" y="-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.30"></use>
                        <use xlink:href="#card-wave" x="-1148" y="1234" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.35)"></use>
                        <use xlink:href="#card-wave" x="-1148" y="1111" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.25)"></use>
                        <use xlink:href="#card-wave" x="48" y="8" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.20)"></use>
                        <use xlink:href="#card-wave" x="1148" y="113" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.15)"></use>
                        <use xlink:href="#card-wave" x="48" y="16" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.99)"></use>
                      </g>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
```

As below the curves are smooth

[image]

However when the screen size is more. It looks like the below. the curve gets bumpy.
[image]

I tried changing a few things it did not work, I need to know which value I need to tune in.

Comment: What is your screen resolution? That might have something to do with it...

Comment: It is a svg, so I was expecting it to fit and work same on any screen

Comment: Well, if the curve is close to a straight line (I'm not sure how to explain this), the screen's pixels are on different heights, and the subtle differences in height change makes different pixels on different levels light up, and it looks like it's not a curve, but if you view it on a higher resolution screen (like a mobile device), it will most likely not be curved.

Comment: The results of drawing a line that is almost horizontal (also happens for vertical). The effect is called "aliasing". You can also see it happening a little in the "good" image around the bottom of the curve at the right.

Comment: Remove preserveAspectRatio="none"